# Expose static function in COM?

Tags: vba, vb6

I have a VB6 DLL project that exposes a number of classes as COM objects to projects that reference the DLL.

I also have several functions in a BAS module. Is there any way to expose these static functions to projects that reference the DLL? I created a test project. It can access the classes but not the static functions, even though they are marked as public.

Is this even possible? Or can I only expose classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you copy the code to a new class & set that classes instancing property to `GlobalMultiUse` in the designer then any public members of that class get added to the global namespace so you can use `ProjectName.XXX`.

This works fine in calls between VB6/VBA but for other callers you will need to create an instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks. For me, it wasn't necessary to use `ProjectName.XXX`. I can simple reference the symbol directly. However, if I try to do this within the same DLL project, I get a *symbol is not defined* error. Within the project, the only way to reference the function is by creating an instance of the class. Do you know if there's any way around that?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I had forgotten that it wont work within the same project.  The way it works for external COM callers is to use stub code to create an instance of the class invisibly and call across a hidden instance variable, but when you work within the same project that plumbing is bypassed.  You are always going to need an instance.  You could always make cGlobalMuClass.XXX() a simple call to fXXX() which is declared in a bas and use the latter inside the DLL project.